# StringBuffer in flutter doesn't working as expected

Tags: dart, flutter, stringbuffer

I am currently just started a Flutter project and is found quite frustrated when playing around with the StringBuffer class, I am having the below codes which format and apply the url to my class;

```
Connector._baseUri = baseUri;
if (Connector._baseUri.endsWith("/"))
  Connector._baseUri = Connector._baseUri.substring(0, Connector._baseUri.lastIndexOf('/'));
Connector._baseUri = new StringBuffer([Connector._baseUri, "/"]).toString();
```

However the initial value of `baseUri` is `http://locahost/test////`, but the final value of `_baseUri` is then be settled as `[http://localhost/test, /]` which I may expect a simple `http://localhost/test/`, have also tried `.write()` and `.writeAll()`, any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`StringBuffer`](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/1.24.3/dart-core/StringBuffer-class.html) has an optional parameter in the constructor, which will take any object and call `toString()` on it. The result of your code above is just toString() on a List. If you want to write an Iterable to the buffer, you instead want to use [`StringBuffer.writeAll`](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/1.24.3/dart-core/StringBuffer/writeAll.html) which will iterate over the values and add each string to the buffer.

```
final buffer = new StringBuffer();
buffer.writeAll([Connector._baseUri, "/"]);
return buffer.toString()
```

Although with only two values you could also just use [`string interpolation`](https://www.dartlang.org/guides/language/language-tour#strings) instead.

```
return '${Connector._baseUri}/';
```